# Inserting associative array into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to insert the following array into a mysql table with columns name,title,url,logo. I created the table and wrote a query to transfer the array. But it was inserting the last line of the array and leaving remaining... plz help me...
this is my array

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("media", $con);

$featured = array();

$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');

$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');

$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');

$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');



 $sql  = "INSERT INTO featured";


   $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($featured))."`)";


   $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $featured)."') ";


   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your array is 2D. You must do this in a `foreach()` loop. We assume all the array values have _already_ been escaped via `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

Comment: foreach ($featured as $sql){

  $sql  = "INSERT INTO featured";

   // implode keys of $featured...
   $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($featured))."`)";

   // implode values of $featured...
   $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $featured)."') ";

   // execute query...
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   
   }

Comment: i have tried something like that, but dint work

Comment: With that loop, you are overwriting `$sql` inside the loop. Use a different index:  `foreach ($featured as $feature)`

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop through the `$featured` array:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("media", $con);
$featured = array();
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');

foreach ($featured as $array) {
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO featured";
    $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($array))."`)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $array)."') ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Or to INSERT several records in one query as suggested:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO featured";
$sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($featured[0]))."`) VALUES"; // make sure that $featured contains the same number of key=>value pairs
foreach ($featured as $array) {
    $sql .= " ('".implode("', '", $array)."'),";
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1); // remove last comma
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Please read on [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: do not run a single query per row, insert multiple rows at once instead.

Comment: Right - initialize the `INSERT INTO (columns...) VALUES` outside the loop, then use the loop to append parenthetical values lists `('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),...`

Comment: Or use a prepared statement with parameterized values that get assigned each time through the loop

Comment: i was thinking there is a possibility that some of the records do not contain all the fields. this is okay if all of the inserted fields have the same number of elements with the same position of all the key and value pairs

Answer (score 1):

you can use `multiple insert` query as `INSERT INTO (column1, column2,...) VALUES ('row1a', 'row1b'..), ('row2a', 'row2b'..)...`

```
    $featured = array();
    $featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
    $featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
    $featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
    $featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO featured ";


   $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($featured))."`)";
   $sql .= " VALUES ";


  for( $i=0; $i < count($featured); $i++) {
    $sql .= "('". implode("', '", $featured[$i])."') "; 
    if( $i < (count($featured) - 1) )
      $sql .= ", ";
  }
```

See it in action [here](http://codepad.org/g69iAiCN).

Answer (score 0):

As hakra suggested you can insert multiple rows using one mysql query by making the following change to your code:

```
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');
$featured[] = array('name' => '', 'title' => '', 'url' => '', 'logo' => '');

$sql  = "INSERT INTO featured";
$sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($featured))."`)";
$sql .= " VALUES "; // moved parenthetical grouping to foreach loop below
foreach ($featured as $feature) {
    $sql .= "('".implode("', '", $featured)."'), "; // note comma after each parenthetical grouping
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -2); // we'll cut off the last ", " added to the string

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)! You should be using PDO or mysqli instead of mysql_ anyway, but that's a whole other discussion.

What you want to do is this:

```
// ========================================================
// Define insert rows. Note the colon before each key name. 
// That's there because we'll be passing this to a PDOStatement as bound 
// parameters. Depending on the logic of your program there may be different 
// ways you want to handle this.
// ========================================================
$featured = array();
$featured[] = array(':name' => '', ':title' => '', ':url' => '', ':logo' => '');
$featured[] = array(':name' => '', ':title' => '', ':url' => '', ':logo' => '');
$featured[] = array(':name' => '', ':title' => '', ':url' => '', ':logo' => '');
$featured[] = array(':name' => '', ':title' => '', ':url' => '', ':logo' => '');


// ========================================================
// Create the PDO object. Define your query and prepare a statement. I use the 
// INSERT SET syntax rather than the INSERT VALUES syntax purely for readability. 
// Either will work with PDO. Also, most programmers don't set the query_str as a 
// separate variable as I do here. I find it improves readability.
// ========================================================
$db_obj = new PDO (/*connection params go here */); 
$query_str = "INSERT INTO featured SET
    name = :name, 
    title = :title, 
    url = :url, 
    logo = :logo"; 
$query_obj = $db_obj->query ($query); 


// ========================================================
// Loop through your rows in $featured and execute the SQL query, passing the
// new row of parameters each time.
// ========================================================
foreach ($featured as $row) {
    $query_obj->execute ($row);
}
```